# Include executable php script of 1 million links

Tags: php, hyperlink, incremental-compiler

I am a front end developer (html, css, Wordpress) who is starting to dabble in .js and .php.

I want to create a page similar to the www.milliondollarhomepage.com

I want every one of those million pixels to point at a series of links:

**Html**

```
<div class="b">
<a href="/1/"><img class="a" src="/images/1pixelpic.png"></a>
<a href="/2/"><img class="a" src="/images/1pixelpic.png"></a>
<a href="/3/"><img class="a" src="/images/1pixelpic.png"></a>
```

---Up To ---->

```
<a href="/999998/"><img class="a" src="/images/1pixelpic.png"></a>
<a href="/999999/"><img class="a" src="/images/1pixelpic.png"></a>
<a href="/1000000/"><img class="a" src="/images/1pixelpic.png"></a>
</div>
```

**css**

```
.a { float:left; }
.b { width:1000px;height:1000px; }
```

This is too long. It crashes in notepad++.

How do I write a .php include script that would look like:

```
<include php path="mymillionlinks.php">
```

And that file would look like

```
<div class="b">
<php write>

if call "<a href="/{1}/"><img class="a" src="/images/1pixelpic.png"></a>" < 1 000 000

then write "<a href="/{1+1}/"><img class="a" src="/images/1pixelpic.png"></a>"

<end php>
</div>
```

My php is not good enough yet. I hope I have explained myself well. Thanks.
Archie.

Comment: cant people do anything original?

Comment: It's probably easier to serve the homepage as a single graphic, rather than many small images. As CodeAngry says, pixel blocks on MDHP were sold in minimum sizes anyway - you can't render any text or logo with a single pixel `:-)`.

Answer (score 1):

You need good `php` for this and good `sql` and good `caching` or static image generation with map. And there are multiple approaches to the functionality.

And if you code php in notepad++, you are already defeated. There's are IDEs for us, php devs.

As far as I remember, he only sold pixels in 10x10 batches minimum. Look at his grid. Doing 1x1 will keep you quite busy.

**UPDATE**

In **frontend** part you need a method of selection pixel regions and upload their image and setup link. And always do 10x10px increments. Pixel fonts fit 10px heights so that's the starting point.

In **backend** part:

- Database stores regions *(from and to coordinate pairs)*, link urls and actual uploaded images.
- On each new added image you clear the cached version of HTML and generate a new one when the page is shown first time with a clear cache.
- That new one is stored until a new user uploads a logo in a region.
- HTML consists of either link or an image map. If you choose an image map, make sure to convert user images into one big image... but it's not really necessary.
- Positioning on the grid has to be absolute. Make sure you split the grid into CSS or just inline CSS to place the logos on the DIV grid. DIV is `position: relative` while child regions are `position: absolute` + `top` and `left`.

This is the story of how it should work. Obviously, you'll need to handle user registration, login, payments, image screening so they don't porn you :) and such.

**PS**: *You don't make a million dollars that easy :) You need to have coding kung-fu.*

Comment: Please! I am sure that if someone mapped it out for me, I could integrate it! Thanks @CodeAngry !

Comment: @ArchieButler Will this do?

Comment: Ok... I see what you are saying... I am not BruceLee.php. I will need to hire a developer because in my concept it has to be pixel by pixel. I managed to write 10 000 urls manually in html and they appeared... But 100 times that must be too much.  I will spend 300-400 dollars on hiring someone professional for a day. Thanks for your feedback though @CodeAngry.

Comment: @ArchieButler 100 character minimum link, times 1.000.000 = 100 MB file (impossible to load EVER). You are aware of that... right? No in 10x10 increments you have: 100 chars times 10.000 = 1MB file.